# GitHub Pages won't render Jekyll include

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I have some liquid markup in my `_includes/` that renders fine on my machine, but when I push to `gh-pages` only the containing div renders. It is supposed to generate the navigation for my site, grouped by page category. I have matched the rubygems on my machine to mimic what I see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages#troubleshooting). Is there something that I am doing wrong with my liquid syntax that is preventing it from rendering in GitHub Pages?

```
<!-- NAVBAR -->
<div class="navbar">
{% assign categories = site.pages | map: 'to_liquid' | map: 'category' %}
{% assign usedCategories = '' %}
{% for category in categories %}{% if category %}
    {% capture categoryToCheck %},{{ category }},{% endcapture %}
    {% unless usedCategories contains categoryToCheck %}
    <h3 style="color: red; text-transform: capitalize;">{{ category | replace: '-', ' ' }}</h3>
        {% for doc in site.pages %}{% if doc.category == category %}
        <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ doc.url }}">{{ doc.title }}</a>
        {% endif %}{% endfor %}
        {% capture usedCategories %}{{ usedCategories }}{{ categoryToCheck }}{% endcapture %}
    {% endunless %}
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Note: I think I've pinpointed the problem down to `map: 'category'` as `site.pages | map: 'to_liquid'` generates the same output (but in a different order). `map: 'category'` extracts the fields out from liquid as it should on my machine, but on `gh-pages` this does not happen. Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

Comment: Hahahaha! Feel free to suggest a more succinct solution to make the categories array distinct in liquid :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this figured out by not using the map property. Here's a snippet:

```
{% assign usedCategories = '' %}
{% for page in site.pages %}
  {% unless usedCats contains page.category %}
    <h3 style="color: red; text-transform: capitalize;">{{ page.category | replace: '-', ' ' }}</h3>
  {% capture usedCategories %}{{ usedCategories }}{{page.category}}{% endcapture %}
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```